# callback function having issues with extracting double pointer

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa-touch, sqlite

```
// issue with the following not returning info or just stalling... but no errors
static int callback(void *voidParam, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{   
    static int k = 0;
    myReturn structReturn;

    char *cTempF = (argv[0] ? argv[0] : "NULL");
    memcpy(&structReturn.cFirstName, cTempF, sizeof(cTempF));// tried strlen(cTempF)... no help

    memcpy(voidParam + k * sizeof(structReturn), &structReturn, sizeof(structReturn));

    k++;
}
```

---

```
myReturn *structReturn = (myReturn*)malloc(sizeof(myReturn) * 20);

rc = sqlite3_exec(db, pSQL, callback, structReturn, &zErrMsg);
```

---

```
typedef struct ReturnTag
{
    char cFirstName[100];
    char cLastName[100];
    short int iAge;
}myReturn;
```

Comment: What are the issues you are having? Please describe the problems more precisely.

Comment: I think I described it pretty well in the comments... nothing is returned back when I do     "memcpy(&structReturn.cLastName, cTempL, strlen(cTempL));" for     "char *cTempF = (argv[0] ? argv[0] : "NULL");" but is returned for     "char cTempF[] = "dog";"

Comment: What do you mean with "nothing is returned"? Are you saying `memcpy` doesn't copy the memory contents from `cTempF` to `structReturn.cFirstName`?

Comment: It is as if the thread is halted... but no errors appear.  But as I said if I do "char cTempF[] = "dog";" .... it works fine.  So it appears to then be something in "char *cTempF = (argv[0] ? argv[0] : "NULL");"... but I can print cTempF.

Comment: Sorry, it's still entirely unclear a) what happens, b) what you expect to happen. Also, the definition of `myReturn` may be helpful.

Comment: What is `//this "short int" block will return if I comment the above 2 blocks` supposed to mean? There's no `return` near that, so does it segfault, or what?

Comment: broke it down a bit more

Comment: Please, describe _in plain text_, using entire sentences, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it... needed:  `memset(&structReturn.cFirstName, '\0', 100);`

```
static int callback(void *voidParam, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{   
    static int k = 0;
    myReturn structReturn;

    char *cTempF = (argv[0] ? argv[0] : "NULL");
    memset(&structReturn.cFirstName, '\0', 100); // <--- needed here
    memcpy(&structReturn.cFirstName, cTempF, strlen(cTempF));

    memcpy(voidParam + k * sizeof(structReturn), &structReturn, sizeof(structReturn));

    k++;
}
```

Comment: More likely you just needed to copy the 0-terminator, `memcpy(&structReturn.cFirstName, cTempF, strlen(cTempF) + 1)`.